# Django bootstrap3_datetime widget in admin site doesn't pass form data

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to replace the standard AdminSplitDateTime widget in my admin site for better functionality (basically I want to display only 'available' dates in my calender which I couldn't find how to do with the default picker).
I decided to use the bootstrap3_datetime widget.

After overriding my field to use the new widget, it doesn't seem to be transferred into the 'clean' method (isn't in self.cleaned_data) for validation.

**models.py**

```
publish_time = models.DateTimeField('Date to publish')
```

**admin.py**

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        bad_dates = []
        #populating bad_dates with application logic

    def clean(self):

        # This will always return None when using the new widget.
        # When working with the default widget, I have the correct value.
        publish_time = self.cleaned_data.get('publish_time', None)


    publish_time = forms.DateTimeField(widget=DateTimePicker(options=
            {"format": "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm",
             "startDate": timezone.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
             "disabledDates": bad_dates,
             })

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

HTML-wise, the widget works well and the text field is populated with the correct date (and with the 'bad_dates' disabled). The problem is that it seems it isn't saved on the form.

I also tried initializing the widget in the **init** method by doing:

```
self.fields['publish_time'].widget = DateTimePicker(options=...)
```

But the result was the same.

[image: Default 'admin site' DateTimepicker that works]

[image: bootstrap3_datetime DateTimePicker that isn't working]

What am I missing here?
Is it even possible to modify widgets in the admin site?

Thanks!

**Update**:
I've analysed the POST request that is sent using each of the widgets.
In the **default** admin widget, I see that it generates two fields: "publish_time_0" (for date) and "publish_time_1" (for time).
In the **bootstrap3** widget, only a single "publish_time" field is sent.

I'm assuming that the admin site understands that the field is a DateTimeField (from models), looks for id_0 and id_1 and that's why it fails.
Does that make sense? Is there anyway around it?